# Center floating DIVs

Tags: html, center

Im trying to center 3 floating DIVs. It works if I give the parent DIV **display:table;** and the child DIVs **display:cell;** which will then act like a table. Is there another way ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Center Div</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        #container
        {               
            text-align:center;
            margin:0 auto;          
            display:table;
        }
        #container div
        {           
            float:left;
            padding:5px;
            display:cell;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="container">
            <div style="background-color:yellow">Text 1</div>
            <div style="background-color:lightgreen">Text 2</div>
            <div style="background-color:lightblue">Text 3</div>            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: would you provide the image you want to do since image also better to understand  the what user want to get

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to assign width to the parent `div` like this :

```
#container
  {               
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;   
    width:150px;    
  }
```

[**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/FAR22/)

Comment: This isn't really centering. It only works if the container width is fixed. text-align:center isn't doing anything.

Comment: @dmzza Why do you cry when the OP himself finds the answer helpful?

Comment: This is not useful, because you have to put the width manually, with display table it's calculated automatically....

Answer (score 0):

I think if you define the width, display: block, margin 0px auto, position:relative  it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Center Div</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        #container
        {               
            text-align:center;
            margin:0 auto; 
            width:200px;

        }
        #container div
        {           
            float:left;
            padding:5px;
            display:cell;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <div id="container">
                <div style="background-color:yellow">Text 1</div>
                <div style="background-color:lightgreen">Text 2</div>
                <div style="background-color:lightblue">Text 3</div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Any reason why you don't want to use a table?

It might solve the purpose. Tables are not all that evil as they are made out to be ;)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
        <title>Center Div</title> 
        <style type="text/css"> 
        #container 
        {                
            text-align:center; 
            margin:0 auto;
        } 
        #container td
        {   
            padding:5px;
        } 
        </style> 
    </head> 
    <body>   
        <div id="container">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="background-color:yellow">Text 1</td>
                    <td style="background-color:lightgreen">Text 2</td>
                    <td style="background-color:lightblue">Text 3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, actually they are. According to the W3 You should not be using tables for layouts, it's a non-semantic, hack of a way of doing this- see this spec that was written in the year 2000 and has not been modified or changed since: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-TECHS/#tech-avoid-table-for-layout

Comment: You should really, really not be using tables for positioning nowadays. Tables have their purpose and should used for that purpose only: showing stuff in a table.