# Centering floatin div

Tags: html, centering

I would like to let float some div with a fixed size, let's say 300px.
I took the example from [Center floating DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683994/center-floating-divs) 
and I insert the size of the div.
They work OK but when I re size the screen (getting it smaller) they are not anymore in the center.
Moreover I also would like to have some space between the div.

Thanks in advance.

Here the actual code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Center Div</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #container
    {               
        text-align:center;
        margin:0 auto;    

        display:table;
    }
    #container div
    {           
        float:left;
        padding:5px;
        display:cell;
        width: 300px
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="container">
        <div style="background-color:yellow">Text ffffffffffff1<p>ddd</p>
            <p>r&nbsp; </div>
        <div style="background-color:lightgreen">Text fffffffffffff2<p>ddd</p>
            <p>v</div>
        <div style="background-color:lightblue">Text fffffffffffffff3<p>ddd</p>
            <p>b</div>            
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your block to fall to the next 'row' when screen is narrow - set a `min-width` to your container and also set overflow to auto - to trigger scroll.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/muA2u/1/)**

```
#container
    {               
        text-align:center;
        margin:0 50px; 
        min-width: 1036px;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    #container div
    {           
        padding:5px;
        display:inline-block;
        width: 300px;
        margin: 10px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try it:
Remove `float: left` and add `display: inline-block` in `#container div`